# Testing Input Data in React using Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have created a simple form in React and I am using Jest to practice my unit testing. I am currently testing my Form Component that renders the input values into the DOM and it keeps on failing because of the TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined. My goal is for all the input labels to be able to pass.

**FormComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react'

const FormComponent = (props) => {
return (
    <main>

        <form>
            <input type="text" value = {props.data.firstName}  name = "firstName" placeholder = "First Name" onChange = {props.handleChange} /> <br/>
            <input type="text" value = {props.data.lastName}  name = "lastName" placeholder = "Last Name" onChange = {props.handleChange} /> <br/>
            <input type="text" value = {props.data.age}  name = "age" placeholder = "Age" onChange = {props.handleChange} /> <br/>
            <input type="text" value = {props.data.location}  name = "location" placeholder = "Location" onChange = {props.handleChange} /> <br/>
            <br/>
            <label>
                <input 
                    type = "radio"
                    value = "Male"
                    name = "gender"
                    checked = {props.data.gender === "Male"}
                    onChange = {props.handleChange}
                    /> Male
                    <br/>
            </label>
            <label>
                <input 
                    type = "radio"
                    value = "Female"
                    name = "gender"
                    checked = {props.data.gender === "Female"}
                    onChange = {props.handleChange}
                    /> Female
                    <br/>
            </label>

            <br />
            <br />
            
            <button>Submit</button>
            <br />
            <br />
            <h1>Entered information: </h1>
            <h3>Your name: {props.data.firstName} {props.data.lastName} </h3>
            <h3>Your age: {props.data.age} </h3>
            <h3>Gender: {props.data.gender} </h3>
            <h3>Location: {props.data.location} </h3>
                   
        </form>
    </main>
  )
}


export default FormComponent
```

**FormComponent.test.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import FormComponent from './FormComponent'
import Enzyme,{
configure,
shallow,
mount,
render } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16"

Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter() });

global.React = React;
global.Enzyme = Enzyme;
global.shallow = shallow;
global.render = render;
global.mount = mount;

describe("Form Input Data", () => {
    it("should render the first name", () => {
        const component = shallow(<FormComponent 
          name = "firstName" label = "First Name"  />)
        const label = component.find('label')
        expect(label).toHaveLength(1);
        expect(label.prop('htmlFor')).toEqual('firstName');
        expect(label.text()).toEqual('First Name');
    
        const input = component.find('input');
        expect(input).toHaveLength(1)
        expect(input.prop('type')).toEqual('text')
        expect(input.prop('name')).toEqual('firstName')
        expect(input.prop('id')).toEqual('firstName')
    })
})
```

**Testing Results**

[image: Test Results]

This is my first time testing in React using Jest and I have no idea how to get my component to pass. I really appreciate all possible solutions. Thanks.

Comment: There is no `data` passed as props to `FormComponent` in your test.

Comment: @SamR. - If there is no data passed as props, where in my code do I need to fix in order it to read the "firstName" property? I'm confused.

Comment: You're reading the `firstName`, `lastName`, `age` and `location` from a `data` object. These need to be passed like `<FormComponent data={{ firstName: '', lastName: '', ... }} />` in your test.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I never passed in the data from the props and I had no idea how to do it. Here is the solution:

```
describe("Form Input Data", () => {
    it("should render the first name", () => {
        const component = shallow(<FormComponent 
          data = {{firstName: ''}}  />)
        const input = component.find('input').first();
        expect(input).toHaveLength(1)
        expect(input.prop('type')).toEqual('text')
        expect(input.prop('name')).toEqual('firstName')
    })
})
```